# Looping to FINITIE depth of children

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on an image gallery and need to some assistance with looping over the categories. The next depth is a known setting in the gallery config's file, so this isn't a question about looping over an infinite depth, but much rather the most effecient way to loop over a known depth, and output all of the results.

Essentially, I want to create a `<select>` box which contains all of the categories defined in the system, including children, grand-children, etc.

The categories are stored in the database as follows (there are other fields, but they're not relevant):

```
+----+--------+--------------+
| id | parent |     name     |
+----+--------+--------------+
|  1 |    0   | Parent 1     |
|  2 |    1   | Child Lvl  1 |
|  3 |    2   | Child Lvl 2  | 
|  4 |    0   | Parent 2     |
+----+--------+--------------+
```

Any category that has a `parent` == 0 is considered itself a top-level parent. As I mentioned already, the maximum depth is known and predetermined, so I would like to output something like this:

```
Parent 1
  - Child Lvl 1
    - Child Lvl 2
Parent 2
```

I had thought that this would be possible a `while` loop, but for some reason this causes PHP to enter an infinite loop.

Here's the code that I have tried so far:

```
$sql = $_database->prepare("SELECT `id`, `name` FROM `".TBL_PREFIX."categories` WHERE `parent` = '0' ORDER BY `name` ASC");
$sql->execute();
while($cat = $sql->fetchObject())
{
    $html.= "\n\t".'<option value="'.$cat->id.'"';
    $html.= (array_key_exists('selected_val', $options) && $options['selected_val'] == $cat->id) ? ' selected="selected"' : '';
    $html.= (array_key_exists('disabled_vals', $options) && in_array('', $options['disabled_vals'])) ? ' disabled="disabled"' : '';
    $html.= '>'.$cat->name.'</option>';

    $childSql = $_database->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) AS `total` FROM `".TBL_PREFIX."categories` WHERE `parent` = :parent");
    $childSql->execute(array(':parent' => $cat->id));

    $numChildren = $childSql->fetchObject();
    $numChildren = $numChildren->total;
    $parentId = $cat->id;

    while($numChildren > 0)
    {
        for($i = 0; $i < (MAX_CAT_DEPTH - 1); $i++)
        {
            $children = $_database->prepare("SELECT `id`, `name` FROM `catgeories` WHERE `parent` = :parent ORDER BY `name` ASC");
            $children->execute(array(':parent' => $parentId));

            while($child = $children->fetchObject())
            {
                $html.= "\n\t".'<option value="'.$child->id.'"';
                $html.= (array_key_exists('selected_val', $options) && $options['selected_val'] == $child->id) ? ' selected="selected"' : '';
                $html.= (array_key_exists('disabled_vals', $options) && in_array('', $options['disabled_vals'])) ? ' disabled="disabled"' : '';
                $html.= '>'.$child->name.'</option>';

                $parentId = $child->id;

                $childSql = $_database->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) AS `total` FROM `".TBL_PREFIX."categories` WHERE `parent` = :parent");
                $childSql->execute(array(':parent' => $parentId));
                $numChildren = $childSql->fetchObject();
                $numChildren = $numChildren->total;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Could anyone suggest the correct manner to go about this. I'd rather not play around too much with the DB structure, since I believe that the one I have already is more than adequate for the requirement here - this is not a question about infinite depth as other questions.

Comment: The easiest way to deal with a recursive structure is a recursive function. Refactor it into something like `getChildren($parentId, $currentDepth, $depthLimit)` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ugly try mptt algorithm instead to avoid recursive statements. Zebra MPTT it's a good solution. Gedmo Tree it's better.